# Controller classes show as unused when its used

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, autowired

I have a Spring Boot Web API application in IntelliJ. Project compiles and APIs are working correctly.  It's setup with `@Autowired`, `@Controller`, `@Service`, `@Repository`, etc.

However, it keeps showing the classes as grey (unused). How can I show it to be used? Or is the way it's in default, and no way to remove this warning error? It's doing this similarly for services and repository classes.

[image]

**Note:**

How can I fix or turn off the warning? I had something similar at my last company, but they got rid of it. Trying to fix it on my local desktop computer.

Comment: Use Alt+Enter on the classname and disable (suppress) the inspection for classes annotated with `@RestController`. That said, I've experienced that recent versions of IntelliJ seem to be occasionally having issues with these "unused" inspections, so restarting IntelliJ or rebuilding your project might solve it (temporarily) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same project, a class is called used when it is referenced by another class or variable.
If you access this class through the browser interface, the IDE will not think that this class is “used”.

Comment: how can I fix this or turn off the warning? I had something similar at my last company, but they got rid of it,  trying to do it on my local desktop, thanks